# SQL Server code optimization when a single procedure gets called multiples times inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this `AuditLogProc` stored procedure which execute different stored procedures and logs the `StartTime` and `EndTime` of different stored procedure executions by calling yet another stored procedure `AuditLogProcDetails` every time as shown in the code below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dba].[AuditLogProc]
    @Id AS INT,
    @ProcessId AS INT
AS
BEGIN 
    TRY
        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppPopTimeInc @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppPopTimeInc', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppPopTimeIncDetails @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppPopTimeIncDetails', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppObsResultsAggInc @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppObsResultsAggInc', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppPricedDetailsInc @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppPricedDetailsInc', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppPricedDetailsIncDetails @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppPricedDetailsIncDetails', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

        SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE();

        EXEC AppLoggedData @Id, @ProcessId;

        BEGIN
            EXEC [dba].[AuditLogProcDetails] @Id, @ProcessId, 'Exiting AppLoggedData', @StartTime, GETDATE()
        END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT 
            @ErrorMessage = error_message(),
            @errorState = error_state();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH

    RETURN
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the best way to call the same procedure `AuditLogProcDetails` every time after different stored procedures gets called i.e including the `BEGIN` and `END` block?
2. Since the `AuditLogProcDetails` procedure gets called multiple times, how can I refactor it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it seems you want to track down your execution time statistics. To do that, I could recommend you a better way: 
If you use [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql) instead of that, you will get not only the execution time but a whole branch of other statistics about your database. There is only one drawback using this method:

It shows statistics for stored procedures in the cache. To eliminate that drawback, you can create a one minute job that stores the current result of that view.
Later, when you want to check the running time of your queries, you can select from the table where you store the results.

In that way, you will not only have some statistics about your stored procedures, but you will have historical data that shows what procedure became your bottleneck and you will be able to check not only execution time but IO statistics and other cool stuff too.

Comment: That helps , Thanks